# Can I detect on runtime the lack of a dependency that must be provided according to pom?

Tags: maven, dependency-management

I'm working in a big project with lots of modules (they are portlets), and dependency management is becoming harder and harder. We have problems like that some jars are used by all portlets and still not provided for the server, so we are including them in every WEB-INF/lib, or dependencies are declared but not used at all, and stuff like that.
I'm trying to clean up that mess, but I'm afraid of making a mistake and not detecting it until it is too late.
Lets say I mark a dependency as "provided", and it is needed in a strange business case I forgot to test, and the server does not provide such a  dependency.
Organization is bureaucratic, and I can not access the server to check the actual presence of a given jar. 
Is there any way I can make the a check for dependencies once the war is installed, and see if everything is there and accessible?
War files contain a copy of pom.xml in META-INF, so at least part of the information is there.
I would love to see something like

```
INFO: Checking provided dependency org.drools-drools-core-4.0.7........done  
ERROR: Checking provided dependency org.drools-drools-compiler-4.0.7........FAIL
```

in the logs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such tool since all things you're talking about happen in run-time. You'll have to trace all `ClassNotFoundException` logs and find artifacts that cointain given classes, e.g. using [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/). That's the best I figured out some time ago having similar case. Far more easy is to check if you have some declared and unused dependencies or undeclared and used (as transitives) by doing `mvn dependency:analyze`. It usually works pretty well, but be aware it uses Maven 2 dependency resolution, so it can lie sometimes when using Maven 3. From my experience, it doesn't happen very often, but sometimes it does and causes some problems though.

Comment: What you are saying is what I am doing right now... dependency:analize and look for class not found exceptions...but I really like to find a way to do it more automatically. I can't believe no one has done it right now.